# TeXstudio compiling issues following El Capitan 10.11.1

Tags: texstudio

I have been using TexStudio for the past few months and very much enjoy the program.
Please excuse me for disturbing you, but I have just installed the Mac El Capitan 10.11.1 update (the most recent version that was released the 21st of October), and it seems that this new update is not compatible with the compiling feature of TeXstudio version 2.10.4. I can still use the "build and view" option, but the compiling feature no longer appears to work - compiling will start but then it will just exit "normally".
I have changed commands to "/Library/TeX/texbin" from "user/textbin" and added "/Library/TeX/texbin" to my command ($path), but nothing appears to work.
Is there some way to resolve this issue, so that compiling will function?
This is my first post. Please excuse any inaccuracies of mine. Thank you!